# Assembler and MIPS question for understanding

Tags: mips

I have this question and I am not sure how to solve the question right.
The location src contains the word 0x12348765.
In register $t1 is the word 0x87654321.
What value comes after executing these commands in register $t1:

```
la $s0, src
lb $t1, 1($s0)
```

My question: what happens in the 2nd line of command? What is the difference, if you use 0($s0) instead?

I am not sure what values will be taken, either 65 or 87?

Comment: Why not tun it and see for yourself?

Comment: Your problem statement is mixing words, which occupy 4 bytes, and bytes, which occupy one byte, of course. When doing this mixing, it is important to understand endian-ness, which for today's MIPS is typically, little endian. So, break 0x12348765 into 4 separate bytes, using little endian, and give each byte its own address. Then it should be obvious which byte value 1($s0) and 0($s0) refer to. Also, be aware that `lb` sign extends (and any prior value in the target register is unused & lost)...